# TreeView Check/UnCheck all child items

Tags: c#, treeview

How do i check/uncheck all child items in TreeView?
Probably error happened when one of items become to selected state and child items checked/unchecked buggy.

**[Link to VS 2010 Project+Exe](http://www.sendspace.com/file/2nrt2a)**

**[Video on YOUTUBE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kviRgkpUiMs)**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.CheckBoxes = true;
        treeView1.BeginUpdate();
        treeView1.Nodes.Add("1111");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2222");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2222");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2222");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2222");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("3333");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("4444");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("4444");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("4444");
        treeView1.EndUpdate();

        treeView1.ExpandAll();
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.BeginUpdate();

        foreach (TreeNode Node in e.Node.Nodes)
        {
            Node.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
        }

        treeView1.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: What? if you need to check all child nodes then do it recursively.

Comment: You should read the [Remarks section of the TreeView class MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx)

Comment: Andrey you need to do something that calls recursively for example 
`public void UncheckAllNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = false;
        CheckChildren(node, false);
    }
}`

Comment: for the CheckChildern(node,false) do this `private void CheckChildren(TreeNode rootNode, bool isChecked)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
    {
        CheckChildren(node, isChecked);
        node.Checked = isChecked;
    }
}`

Comment: @DJKRAZE:  Why not answer the question?

Comment: **I know about recursion, but that won't help. Yes it's works, but buggy.**

**http://pastebin.com/ByJRbJiP**

Comment: This doesn't look much like a bug.  You get the screenshot simply by clicking the first checkbox then clicking the 2nd and 3rd.  It isn't clear why that would be wrong and what you want differently.

Comment: Hans Passant, okay so how i disable clicking on treeview items and only allow to check/uncheck it.

Comment: I am going to try your code .. also I think that you have the code in the wrong event(s) I saw your YouTube video, I am going to re create your project and try it.. hold on a few minutes

Comment: Andrey the code works I will post the methods that I used to get this to work.. so actually what I have provided you in the answer did work.. you did not apply the method properly I will provide the methods

Comment: DJ KRAZE Maybe you just upload somewhere your C# project, because what all i do works buggy.

Comment: maybe you should send me your project.. It works perfectly fine what I copied and pasted into my form.. your code exactly into a new form on my project and it works well .. I would be interested in seeing your full code..

Comment: Look... Code: http://pastebin.com/cjimZhfy and Screenshot: http://s017.radikal.ru/i405/1302/e0/7b09f6a9204c.png

Comment: Also! It's works correct with keyboard(space to check/uncheck) but wrong with mouse.

Comment: I'am not one who mess with it. That probably .NET or "user32.dll" bug. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9d717ce0-ec6b-4758-a357-6bb55591f956/

Comment: Andrey Petrovich, I fixed the issue for you and have pasted code that works I just double checked it

Comment: @AndreyPetrovich did you solved your problem? I have same situation...

Answer (score 5):

using your code that you have in the Form_Load keep that code it works and add these 2 methods in your code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.CheckBoxes = true;
    treeView1.BeginUpdate();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add("1111");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2222");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2222");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2222");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2222");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("3333");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("4444");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("4444");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("4444");
    treeView1.EndUpdate();
    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}

private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode childNode in e.Node.Nodes)
    {
        childNode.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: DJ KRAZE That not help's. So i make video to show you what wrong.
**http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kviRgkpUiMs**
Also i fix video link.

Comment: I provided you with a newer version I hope this corrects your problem it is working as well this is a cleaner version of code for you

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I've figured out was the following:

- To perform the selection I used Linq:

  `if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0) e.Node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(tnc => tnc.Checked != e.Node.Checked).ForEach(tn => tn.Checked = e.Node.Checked);`
- Then to handle the event selection I extended the TreeView class:

  `public class MyTV : TreeView
  {
  protected bool TopOfCascade;
  TreeNode startNode;
  public Action FinishedCheckEventsDelegate;
  public Action InitiateCascadeCheckEventsDelegate;
  public MyTV()
    : base()
  {
    TopOfCascade = false;
    startNode = null;
  }
  protected override void OnBeforeCheck(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnBeforeCheck(e);
    if (!TopOfCascade && !e.Cancel)
    {
      TopOfCascade = true;
      startNode = e.Node;
      if (InitiateCascadeCheckEventsDelegate != null)
   InitiateCascadeCheckEventsDelegate();
    }
  }
  protected override void OnAfterCheck(TreeViewEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnAfterCheck(e);
    if (startNode == e.Node && e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
    {
      if (FinishedCheckEventsDelegate != null) FinishedCheckEventsDelegate();
      TopOfCascade = false;
      startNode = null;
    }
  }`

  In the host control, you can hook the pre and post cascade events and iterate over all checked/unchecked tree nodes avoiding a lot of cross event firing. You control the cascade via some container.

I got the ForEach to IEnumerable from the following an implementation from the web:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
  if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
  foreach (T item in source)
  {
    action(item);
  }
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer (from Hans Passant):

[Winforms treeview, recursively check child nodes problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174412/winforms-treeview-recursively-check-child-nodes-problem?rq=1)

Im writing it as answer, not comment to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
        {
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                /* Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current 
                Checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed. */
                this.CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
            }

        }
    }

   private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = nodeChecked;
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                // If the current node has child nodes, call the CheckAllChildsNodes method recursively. 
                this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = nodeChecked;
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
            }
        }
    }
    private void treeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
        {
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                if (!e.Node.Checked)
                {
                    this.CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
                }
            }
        }

        if (e.Node.Parent != null)
        {
            TreeNode n = e.Node;
            while (n.Parent != null)
            {
                if (n.Checked)
                {
                    n.Parent.Checked = true;
                }
                n = n.Parent;
            }
        }

    }
```