# How to unchecked child node if parent node unchecked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to unchecked child node if parent node is unchecked.according to my code if I checked a child node parent node get selected. It is the write way but when I unchecked the parent node child node still remain checked. I have done some following code at AfterCheck event.

```
private bool updatingTreeView;
        private void treSelector_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (updatingTreeView) return;
            updatingTreeView = true;
            SelectParents(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
            updatingTreeView = false;
        }

private void SelectParents(TreeNode node, Boolean isChecked)
        {
            var parent = node.Parent;

            if (parent == null)
            {
                //CheckAllChildren(treSelector.Nodes, false);
                return;
            }

            if (isChecked)
            {
                parent.Checked = true; // we should always check parent
                SelectParents(parent, true);
            }
            else
            {
                if (parent.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Any(n => n.Checked))
                    return; // do not uncheck parent if there other checked nodes

                SelectParents(parent, false);
            }
        }
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at all of the available events and investigate what each one does.. for example `TreeView AfterCheck Event`? also there are many examples in the `Related` section on this current page if you take the time to scroll to the right hand side of the page you will see

Comment: Clearly the code is doing it backwards, you want to iterate the child nodes and note the parent nodes.  Do beware of [a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174412/winforms-treeview-recursively-check-child-nodes-problem/3174824#3174824) in TreeView that makes it unreliable when you click too fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write another method like this:

```
void checkChildNodes(TreeNode theNode, bool isChecked)
{
    if (theNode == null) return;
    theNode.Checked = isChecked;
    foreach(TreeNode childNode in theNode.Nodes)
    {
        checkChildNodes(childNode, isChecked);
    }
}
```

Comment: at first time child node is not getting checked when i click second time on child check box it get checked.

Answer (score 0):

I have added following code in aftercheck event before `updatingtreeview=false`

```
 if (e.Node.Checked==false)
            {
                if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    /* Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current 
                    Checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed. */
                    this.CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
                }
            }
```

and method is

```
private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                node.Checked = nodeChecked;
                if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    // If the current node has child nodes, call the CheckAllChildsNodes method recursively. 
                    this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
                }
            }
        }
```

it is working fine..