# TreeView - how to "replicate" Node.Checked state to child nodes?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, .net-4.5

I have code like this:

```
private void treeview1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    // I tried this, but not helped
    // treeview1.BeginUpdate(); 

    if (e.Node.Level == 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode item in e.Node.Nodes)
        {
            item.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
        }
    }

    // this is a method that executes slow enough, 
    // that I can click multiple times before it ends
    RefreshListOfSelectedItems(); 

    // I tried this, but not helped
    // treeview1.EndUpdate();
 }
```

Basically - this is supposed to copy "Checked" state to child nodes, but problem is that when I click on checkbox fast enough - everything mess up, because (I think) my event handler executes slower than I can click.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void checkChildren(TreeNode node)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tn in node.Nodes)
            tn.Checked = true;
    }

    //After check event for treeView
    void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Checked) checkChildren(e.Node);
    }
```

i checked this one and is workin for child and and all their children.

Comment: Well, this will not help. I found an answer and what is the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174412/winforms-treeview-recursively-check-child-nodes-problem?rq=1

Comment: Try to double-click few times and see what will happen.